# how do i select the previous li using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an unordered list, but there are headers within it for different categories.

```
<ul>
    <h2>header1</h2>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <h2>header2</h2>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to loop through them and order them by the date, but the headers are throwing it off.

I'm looping through using:

```
var list = $('#articleList');
list.children("li").each(function () {
    ...
}
```

and I'm using this within the loop to select the one before it:

```
var prev = $(this).prev("li");
```

For some reason, prev selects the headers if you are on the list item after the header instead of the list item before them. So my sorting ends up being correct within the headers, but I need the whole thing to be ordered, not just in sections.

Comment: Can you post your actual code?

Comment: A `<h2>` is no valid child of a `<ul>` element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will have to do with the HTML parsing. By [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2), lists may only contain `<li>` elements and nothing else. So, your browser will build a different DOM, e.g. by wrapping the headings into list items (HTML5 wil specify what exactly to do with invalid HTML). Use your DOM inspector to view the actual DOM tree (context menu -> Inspect element).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var prev = $(this).prevUntil('li').first();
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your improper HTML is messing up the jQuery .`prev()` method. `ul` elements should not have `h2` elements as children.

You should instead have your `h2` elements be children of `li` elements, making your HTML look like this:

```
<ul id="articleList">
    <li class="header"><h2>header1</h2></li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li class="header"><h2>header2</h2></li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Notice that each `li` element which contains an `h2` elements has a class of "header." You can then loop through each non-header `li` element like this:

```
var list = $('#articleList');
list.children("li:not(.header)").each(function () {
    ...
}
```

And fetch the previous non-header `li` element like this:

```
var prev = $(this).prev("li:not(.header)");
```

Answer (score 1):

This works with your html:

```
    var prevLI = $('ul li:last').prevAll('li:first');
    $('body').append('<h2>Selected: '+ prevLI.text() + '</h2>' );
```

Try it on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/guumaster/4Ax6v/1/